# Delete a standard library map

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I have a `map<long,myClass *> myMap;`
The elements of the myMap were allocated dynamically :
`myMap[1] = new myClass();` etc.
I want to delete all the memory,which was allocated for  `myMap` elements.
is it ok to use `myMap.erase(myMap.begin(),myMap.end());`

Comment: Easy solution: Use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to delete all those dynamic allocated elements first otherwise you may leak memory.

```
for (std::map<long,myClass *>::iterator iter = myMap.begin();
     iter != myMap.end(); ++iter)
{
   delete (*iter).second;
}

myMap.clear();
```

A better way is to use smart pointer instead:

```
std::map<long, std::shared_ptr<myClass> > myMap;
std::shared_ptr<myClass> p(new myClass());
myMap[1] = p;
myMap.clear();  // no need to call delete manually anymore, clear is enough
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you'll need to explicitly iterate through the values and `delete` them.

The best solution though would be to have a `map<long,std::shared_ptr<myClass> >` instead.